# Truncate the value in timestamp column to only date portion,removing the time in Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine-1.2

I want to compare two dates, where a user input date should not be save in Mysql if same date already exist in a column in a One to Many relationships.My problem is, the date column is a timestamp type,thus two same dates has different time,and it will still save in a database,since they are still of 'different value' like '2004-13-12 8:00:00' is different from '2014-13-12 8:07:08'.I can do it in Mysql

```
SELECT date_created 
FROM koleks
WHERE 
-- Truncate the datetime to a date only
DATE(date_created) = '2014-03-12'
AND id = 3942
```

I tried in Doctrine but I am not successful.

```
public function getDateCreate($date,$id) {
    //$date =date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2014-03-12 8:00:00'));this will 
   // $id = 3942;//work
    $q = $this->createQuery('k')
                ->select('k.date_created')
                ->addSelect('k.loan_id')
                ->from('Koleks k')
                ->innerJoin('k.Loans l')
                ->andWhere('k.date_created=?',$date)
                ->andWhere('k.loan_id=?',$id);
               return $q->execute();
```

//action

```
  $dateOfPayment = '2014-01-10';
  $ids = 1234;
  $duplicates = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Koleks')->getDateCreate($dateOfPayment,$id);
                        if (count($duplicates) > 0) {
                           $this->fieldErrors['date_of_payment_'.$loan['id']] = 'Error Duplicate date.';
                        }
                       else {
                             //code to save in database;
                        }
```

Any Ideas?I want to throw an error in action if the date part of two date values has the same value, regardless of its time(Hour,min,sec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine will happily accept `DATE()` function in dql:

```
->andWhere('DATE(k.date_created) = ?', $date)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the DATE() function to remove the time portion of a DATETIME.

Comment: I already Tried it but I want to do that in Doctrine 1.2 query